# Invoking another method which has previouy been used

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to reuse a validation method i created

```
public boolean validRoom(String roomNo){

        String floorNo = roomNo.substring(0,1); 
        String rNo = roomNo.substring(1,3);
        int roomNoI = Integer.parseInt(rNo);
        int floorNoI = Integer.parseInt(floorNo);

        if(!(floorNoI > 7 || floorNoI <= 0 || roomNoI <= 12)){

            System.out.println("sorry room " + floorNoI + roomNoI + " number does not exsist at this hotel");
            return false;

        }

        System.out.println("Floor:- " + floorNoI +"\nRoom:-  "  + rNo );

        return true;
    }
```

how can i just invoke this method when i need to use this validation again in another method rather than duplicating the code?

Answer (score 1):

You create an object of the class, and then you call validRoom while passing in a value - for example (assuming your class is called MyClass):

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.validateRoom(5);
```

If some of your code isn't applicable for the other situation, then you should take the applicable part and make a method out of it.  Also, if you don't want to have to instantiate a class, then you can make your validation method static and then you can call it like MyClass.validateRoom(5)

Comment: cause i wanted to use it further on in the class in a method to checkIn so it use the other method to validate it    public  void checkIn (String roomNo){

        if(roomNo.validRoom() == true){
            System.out.println("checked in");

        }
        else{
            system.out.println("not valid room"

        }
    }    but this is how i thought it would work

Comment: If it's within the same class, then you can just call the method directly as validRoom(roomNo); , as it will know to call the method for the object that you are in.  Alternately, you can explicitly call self.validRoom(roomNo);